# Mongo building a family tree

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to build a family tree with potentially infinite levels of parents and children.  I will also want to find brothers, sisters, cousins, etc. and am a bit confused at the approach of building an array in Javascript when the data only gives parents of every person.

In a MongoDB Collection called "Users" I have the following entries

```
{ id: 1, name: "Target", parents: [3,4] }
{ id: 2, name: "Wife" }
{ id: 3, name: "Dad", parents: [5,6] }
{ id: 4, name: "Mom" }
{ id: 5, name: "Dads Dad", parents: [7,8] }
{ id: 6, name: "Dads Mom" }
{ id: 7, name: "Dads Dads Dad", parents: 9 }
{ id: 8, name: "Dads Dads Mom" }
{ id: 9, name: "Dads Dads Dads Dad" }
{ id: 10, name: "Son", parents: [1, 2] }
{ id: 11, name: "Sons Son", parents: [10] }
{ id: 12, name: "Sons Sons Son", parents: [11] }
{ id: 13, name: "Brother", parents: [3,4] }
{ id: 14, name: "Brothers Son", parents: [13] }
{ id: 15, name: "Uncle", parents: [5,6] }
{ id: 16, name: "Aunt", parents: [5,6] }
{ id: 17, name: "Daughter", parents: [5,6] }
```

I can easily loop every child using the ids and output it but it will not give structure of children of children just loops and outputs.

```
getChildren = function(id) {
    var children = Users.find({parents: id});
    children.forEach(function(child) {
        console.log(child);
        getChildren(child.id);
    });
};
```

I have been trying to create two global variables `ascendants` and `descendants` so that I could loop parents, grandparents, etc. and nest their children and childen's children inside that (for brothers and then nephews, etc). and then similar with descendents.  This has turned complex because of having multiple nests and having to be able to add an entry inside another entry.

Was hoping someone could help me with structuring this. So I could get something that could be built into an HTML/CSS family tree.  To get non-children/parents I would probably have to conditionally loop again?

```
descendents = {
    10: {           // son
        11: {       // grandson
            12: {}  // great grandson
        }
    },
    17: {           // daughter

    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the MongoDB Manual articles on [Modeling Tree Structures](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/). I think that the array of ancestors pattern looks most suitable for your use case.

Comment: wdberkeley, I looked at it and the parents: [1,2] is similar to part of it while the ancestors wouldn't specifically make a tree structure but helps with indexing.  I think I am already partially using what is recommended there and the issue is still in the Javascript interpreting the output as Mongo isn't going to give back nested JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current structure and a slight modification to your implementation, you can find the parents of a given `id` and the children of a given `parent id`.

Let root be the variable which holds the output structure:

```
var root = {};
```

The recursive function to find all the descendants:

```
var getDescendants = function(id,root) {
    var children = Users.find({parents: id});
    children.forEach(function(child) {
        root[child.id] = {"name":child.name};
        getChildren(child.id,root[child.id]);
    });
};

getDescendants (3,root);
```

Sample o/p:

```
 > root
{
        "1" : {
                "10" : {
                        "11" : {
                                "12" : {
                                        "name" : "Sons Sons Son"
                                },
                                "name" : "Sons Son"
                        },
                        "name" : "Son"
                },
                "name" : "Target"
        },
        "13" : {
                "14" : {
                        "name" : "Brothers Son"
                },
                "name" : "Brother"
        }
}
```

The recursive function to find all the ancestors.

```
var getAscendants = function(id,root) {
    var rec = Users.findOne({id: id});
    if(rec.hasOwnProperty("parents")){
      (rec["parents"]).forEach(function(parent) {
        root[parent] = {};
        getAscendants(parent,root[parent]);
    });
    }
};
var root = {};
getAscendants(12,root);
```

> *To get non-children/parents I would probably have to conditionally
>   loop again*

Yes. You could make use of the `$nin` operator.

Comment: Good answer and was exactly what I was trying to do.